# What does this sql mean with not exists?

Tags: mysql, sql

a table like this

```
int char int  int
id  name a_id b_id

SELECT count(*) FROM tbl t1 WHERE b_id = 12 AND NOT EXISTS(select * from tbl t2 where t2.a_id = t1.b_id AND t2.b_id = t1.a_id)
```

I think it at least equals to

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tbl t1 WHERE b_id = 12 AND NOT EXISTS(select * from tbl t2 where t2.a_id = 12 AND t2.b_id = t1.a_id)
```

then what does this mean?

For example, `SELECT a_id FROM tbl t1 WHERE b_id = 12` gives 1,2,3,4

then do following:

```
select * from tbl t2 where t2.a_id = 12 AND t2.b_id = 1 # NULL
select * from tbl t2 where t2.a_id = 12 AND t2.b_id = 2 # exists
select * from tbl t2 where t2.a_id = 12 AND t2.b_id = 3 # exists
select * from tbl t2 where t2.a_id = 12 AND t2.b_id = 4 # NULL
```

so the count(*) will be 2?

Comment: It's the same as a LEFT JOIN with NULL, which is how we used to do this

Comment: Sorry i'm new to sql, can you explain it in descriptive way?

Comment: Well it selects the things in the part of the query that don't appear in the second part of the query

Comment: I have updated post, am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is very interesting because it finds "symmetries" in a_id and b_id with the number 12,so basically it counts the number of rows in the table where b_id=12 except for the ones which have a symmetric pair, like this:

```
| a_id | b_id |
---------------
|  12  |  12  |
|  12  |  2   |
|  2   |  12  |
```

Or more generally speaking, the query skips counting the rows which have a_id=X b_id=12 and there exists another row where a_id=12 and b_12=X.

So the NOT EXISTS is simply there to skip counting rows which have a symmetric pair, I don't know what this can be useful for in most applications but it is interesting nonetheless.

Comment: So if I remove `NOT` from sql, it will return 1 if I have a `a_id:12 b_id:2` record and `a_id:2, b_id:12` record?

Comment: @Sato If you remove the `NOT` then the query will have the meaning of counting the number of symmetric pairs which have a 12 in them. So yes, it would return 1 if those were the only two rows in the table. (sorry for deleting the first comment, misclicked)